# Why is \AA still defined as it was in LaTeX2.09?

Tags: font-encodings

The `\AA` and `\aa` macros are defined in `latex.ltx` as

```
\def \aa {\r a}
\def \AA {\r A}
```

This fails with the `X2` encoding which has no Latin letters. Why didn't the LaTeX team revert to the following definition:

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\AA}{OT1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\aa}{OT1}
\DeclareTextCommand{\aa}{OT1}{\r a}
\DeclareTextCommand{\AA}{OT1}{\r A}
```

Here is a MWE (UPDATED):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % source file encoding
\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc} % cyrillic font encoding
%  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\AA}{OT1}
%  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\aa}{OT1}
%  \DeclareTextCommand{\aa}{OT1}{\r a}
%  \DeclareTextCommand{\AA}{OT1}{\r A}

\begin{document}%

\verb|\AA|=\AA
\verb|\aa|=\aa

\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont

\verb|\AA|=\AA
\verb|\aa|=\aa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question, but for mixed input like that I'd just use a unicode engine and a  font which supports both scripts and input `Å` directly.

Comment: `X2` is not a “proper” LaTeX font encoding, for the precise reason it doesn't contain the Latin alphabet.

Comment: as egreg says the reason it is `X..` not `T..` is because it doesn't follow the rules that underlie the assumptions in the code with respect to latin in the ascii positions and T1-compatible upper/lower case tables. That said something like you suggest would be possible but I have to ask, why would you expect `\AA` to work, if `A` does not work within the scope of that encoding?

Comment: you do not show your output but [I get this with tl2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQcf1.png) which seems to show `\AA` working OK???

Comment: @egreg: X2 encoding contains ancient slavonic letters. There are no enough slots for all such letters in T2* encodings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have exactly same output as in your answer.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov so the example posted does not show any problem, you could have used an example that did not load babel-russian it woudl have been rather clearer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: @DavidCarlisle: I have exactly same output as in your answer is case of `russian-babel` available from CTAN. But I experimented with forthcoming version where workaround for X2 encoding is removed. I believe that  `russian-babel` is not a good place for such workaround. That's where my question raised from.

Comment: 2017. Unicode and Opentype exist and are supported by XeTeX & LuaTeX.

Answer (score 12):

In LaTeX 2.09 the definitions were

```
\def\aa{\accent23a}

\def\AA{\leavevmode\setbox0\hbox{h}\dimen@\ht0\advance\dimen@-1ex%
  \rlap{\raise.67\dimen@\hbox{\char'27}}A}
```

as there was no encoding support, and no `\r` accent defined.

So whatever else is the case `\aa` and `\AA` are not defined as in LaTeX 2.09.

With current latex and your MWE shows that the effective definition in your case is

```
> \AA=macro:
->\OT1-cmd \AA \OT1\AA .
```

and you do get an accented A in X1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % source file encoding
\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc} % cyrillic font encoding
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
%  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\AA}{OT1}
%  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\aa}{OT1}
%  \DeclareTextCommand{\aa}{OT1}{\r a}
%  \DeclareTextCommand{\AA}{OT1}{\r A}


\begin{document}%

\verb|\cyrillicencoding|=\cyrillicencoding

Русский English

\meaning\AA

\verb|\AA|=\AA
\verb|\aa|=\aa

\section{X2}

\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont
\verb|\cyrillicencoding|=\cyrillicencoding

Русский English

\show\AA

\verb|\AA|=\AA (A \r A)
\verb|\aa|=\aa (a \r a)

\show\AA
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The suggested definitions would need to be extended to *all* encodings.

As posted (and as currently in Russian babel) they break `\AA` for (for example) T1 encoding which is bad as it is the main encoding for the Scandinavian languages for which this is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc} % cyrillic font encoding

\showoutput

\setbox0\hbox{foob\aa r}\showbox0

  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\AA}{OT1}
  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\aa}{OT1}
  \DeclareTextCommand{\aa}{OT1}{\r a}
  \DeclareTextCommand{\AA}{OT1}{\r A}

\setbox0\hbox{foob\aa r}\showbox0

\begin{document}%





\end{document}
```

Shows that by default `\aa` in T1  comes from the T1 encoded font, which allows hyphenation and kerning to work correctly

```
\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x27.79877
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 f
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\kern0.27771
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 �
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
```

But after the suggested definitions `\aa` comes from the OT1 font

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x27.8
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 f
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\kern0.27771
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 o
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\kern -1.25 (for accent)
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^W
.\kern -6.25002 (for accent)
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
```

So hyphenation in any word using å is broken.

Comment: David. I have corrected MWE.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I have updated my answer with an example showing problems with the suggested definitions

Answer (score 6):

If you look at `russianb.ldf`, you can see

```
 86 \expandafter\ifx\csname T@X2\endcsname\relax\else
 87   \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\AA}{OT1}
 88   \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\aa}{OT1}
 89   \DeclareTextCommand{\aa}{OT1}{\r a}
 90   \DeclareTextCommand{\AA}{OT1}{\r A}
 91 \fi
```

(line numbers added for reference), which means that, provided the `X2` font encoding has been initialized in the document, the `\AA` and `\aa` commands will do what you propose. Otherwise there is no need for this, as an encoding whose name starts with `T` is supposed to have Latin letters in the corresponding ASCII positions.

Comment: I am maintainer of `babel-russian` and my question was initiated by my desire to remove the indicated lines from `russianb.ldf`. I believe that `russianb.ldf` is not a proper place for such sort of definitions. They should be moved, eg, to `x2enc.def`.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov you could have mentioned in your question that the MWE you had posted did not show the problem:-) The problem with the definitions is that it leaves `\AA` wrong for other encodings, eg T1, would need a similar definition or `\AA` would come from OT1

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov You should mention *why* you'd need `\AA` when the X2 encoding is active.

Comment: @egreg: This is 2nd reason why Russian babel is not a proper place for definition of `\AA`: X2 encoding lacks all latin letters so why there should be an exclusion for `\AA`? So I almost for sure will remove this chunck of code from next release of Russian babel.